# Dual Boot Ubuntu 14.04 and windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot

I had Dual boot System with Ubuntu and Windows 7 ultimate .. Windows 7 Got corrupted so i had to reinstall windows 7 (Ultimate 32bit) ..

When i had the dual boot when the windows wasn't corrupted it used to ask me what OS to Boot

before reinstalling windows 7 I got on ubuntu and moved my important files from windows to ubuntu ...

I made a Boot-able windows 7 USB ...

I inserted the USB into the machine then i started reinstalling windows 7 I formatted it's partitions (Didn't format Ubuntu's) and installed it (Using a USB)

after reinstalling the windows 7 I restarted the computer so i can choose which OS to Boot from but the Boot options never showed up... it only boots up from windows ...

So how can i Boot back from Ubuntu so i can move the files back or at least take them out ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted to https://askubuntu.com/q/799025/37165. Please read [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EasyBCD can add Ubuntu to boot menu from Windows. All you need to do is boot into Windows, download EasyBCD from [here](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) and than follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CHNVBfzZhQ) video that shows you how to do it. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

When reinstalling Windows 7, Windows overwrote Grub.

You can use the [Ubuntu Boot Rescue](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/) live image to repair Grub.

Answer (score 0):

If you find you *cannot* fix the grub bootloader (Windows overwrites it), then this longer procedure will remedy the issue:

1. Make a disk image as it is now, either with a Windows tool such as [Macrium Reflect Free](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx) or a Linux tool such as [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).
2. Make Ubuntu installation media and use it to *reinstall* Ubuntu in the same partition it currently inhabits (likely ext4 formatted). This will, of course, mess up the current Ubuntu installation, but *will* make the partition bootable.
3. Restore the old Ubuntu partition from the image.

This was the only way I could get dual-boot back after "upgrading" from one Windows version to another.

Comment: You couldn't just reinstall grub?

Comment: Correct. I tried a number of tools to rebuild grub, but nothing allowed dual boot after upgrading Windows. Reinstalling Ubuntu from USB stick, and then restoring the partition, did. Perhaps I made a mistake, or missed using the right tool, but the install+restore process only took about half an hour, which was less time than I'd spent trying to fix grub.